# Need to change the position of jqgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, jqgrid

I have to place the jqgrid in a different position rather than the default top left position.I have tried something but it doesn't work. I have included my code here.. Plz check that and give me a solution..

This is html code:

```
<div>
    <table id="table" style="border-spacing: 7px 7px; margin-left: 5px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input style="margin-left: 10px;" type="button" value="Add" id="btn_addusers" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="users_grid" style="left: 300px">
    </table>
</div>
```

This is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn_addusers").click(function() {
        $("#users_grid").clearGridData(true).trigger("reloadGrid");
        $("#users_grid").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            height: 'auto',
            width: 'auto',
            colNames: ['User ID', 'User Name'],
            colModel: [
        { name: 'userid', width: 60 },
        { name: 'username', width: 120 }

    ],

            caption: "Users in Private space"
        });
        var mydata = [
        { userid: "312171", username: "D, Gnana Xavier" },
        { userid: "311763", username: "Sangeetha" },
        { userid: "312185", username: "Amrutha" },
        { userid: "312186", username: "Ramesh" }
        ];
        for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++)
            $("#users_grid").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);

    });
});
```

Comment: I don't recommend you to use `addRowData`. It's the slowest way to fill the grid. Instead of that you should move definition of `mydata` array *before* you create the grid and add `data: mydata` and `gridview: true` to jqGrid options. Additionally I would recommend you to add `id` property to every item of `mydata`. The `id` property will be used as the `id` of `<tr>` elements (rows) of the grid.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks for the suggestion.. That is really a useful info..Will avoid that in future..

Comment: @Oleg i need another help related to jqgrid.. can you pls check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411956/add-new-row-to-a-jqgrid#comment18329608_13411956

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand what you want to do. For example you can use [addRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) to add row to the grid. Alternatively you can add navigator to the grid using `navGrid` and `inlineNav`. In the case you can implement the "Add" button integrated in jqGrid.

Comment: @Oleg As you mentioned in the previous comments to avoid using addRowData.. that's y i tried like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jqGrid creates many *additional outer* divs over the table element. So you should place the `<table>` element inside of `<div>` and you can use styles of the outer div to change position of the table. For example

```
<div style="margin-left: 300px">
    <table id="users_grid"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: i need another help related to jqgrid.. can you pls check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411956/add-new-row-to-a-jqgrid

Answer (score 3):

Ok as @aristos suggested. I am trying to explain my answer.
User position=relative in the div as follows

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <table id="table" style="border-spacing: 7px 7px; margin-left: 5px">
       <tr>
          <td>
            <input style="margin-left: 10px;" type="button" value="Add" id="btn_addusers" />
          </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
    <table id="users_grid" style="left: 300px;position:absolute!important;">
    </table>
</div>
```

Note that

If the position of the parent container is relative **position:relative**
and the postion of the content is **absolute** then it can move in the container.

Now you can use **left** and **top** attribut to move the table.
But it will not go outside of the div.

Comment: @ShekharKumar: Your suggestion will work in case of common `<table>` element, but jqGrid *modify* it and place the `<table>` as the child of another outer div having `position: relative;`. As the result the usage of `position:absolute` will follows that the content (the body) of the table could be not seen at all. So your suggestion will not work in context of the usage with jqGrid.