# Add new row to a jqgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I have a text box and add button. Once the user enters some value in the text box and clicks the add button the text box value should be stored in jqgrid. But the text box value is not getting painted in jqgrid  How to achieve this..?

This is the aspx code:

```
 <div>
    <table>
         <tr>
             <td>
              <span class="SubHeading">Users </span></td>
              <td>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txt_users" runat="server" />
              </td>
               <td>
              <asp:Button ID="btn_addusers" Text="Add" style="margin-left: 10px;"runat="server" />

                </td>                  

                 </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
```

This is the js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn_addusers").click(function() {
        $("#users_grid").trigger("reloadGrid");

        var mydata = $('#txt_users').val();
        $("#users_grid").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            data: mydata,
            gridview: true,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 'auto',
            colNames: ['User ID'],
            colModel: [
        { name: 'userid', width: 180 }


    ],

            caption: "Users in Private space"
        });
        return false;

    });
});
```

Comment: jqgrid here means jquery UI grid or some other grid?

Comment: its just a normal jqgrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should move the definition of `jqGrid` *out of* the `click` handle. The grid can be created *once*. If the user need to add a row to the grid you can use `addRowData`. Alternatively you can use `addRow` which add *empty* row in the grid. You can also use `inlineNav` to integrate "Add" button in the navigator bar of grid. If you would use [toppager: true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) option you would have the pager on top instead of on bottom of the grid. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4402903/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3557663/315935) for details.